When placed on the server, the aiogram bot does not see the env environment
Please help me figure it out. The bot works fine on the local computer, however, when launched from the server, it stops seeing the token, the admin and everything that is located in the env file
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, F
import asyncio
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from aiogram.client.bot import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode

#Подключаем роутеры
from handlers.start.start import start_router
from handlers.profile.profile import profile_router, process_pre_checkout_query, success_payment
from handlers.search_org.search_org import search_router
from handlers.add_organization.add_organization import create_route
from handlers.history_search.history_search import history_router
from handlers.mailing.mailing import mailing_route
from handlers.view_user.view_user import view_router

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('TOKEN_ID')
bot = Bot(token=token, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
dp = Dispatcher()

async def start_bot(bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=321813597, text='Справочник и парсер запущены')

#Регистрируем роутеры
dp.startup.register(start_bot)
dp.include_router(start_router)
dp.include_router(profile_router)
dp.include_router(search_router)
dp.include_router(create_route)
dp.include_router(history_router)
dp.include_router(mailing_route)
dp.include_router(view_router)

dp.pre_checkout_query.register(process_pre_checkout_query)
dp.message.register(success_payment, F.successful_payment)


async def start():
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())

The previous ones using this method (with systemd) work fine. Apparently I do not know any subtleties

You didn't show how you start this, but whatever you do, it must be not loading your .env (if that's where your config is stored)

For example, you could be not setting working dir correctly, so dotenv doesn't find the file. Or something else like this.

that's what the server responds to me when I try to use the bot. The bot starts, but refuses to respond to the buttons, gives this errorОшибка: Telegram server says - Bad Request: chat not found

But everything works on the computer without problems. So, the fact is that there is some kind of failure on the server.

Evidently. Have you seen my comments above? You must be launching the bot differently, between the server and your dev machine. Identify the differences and you'll likely find what's causing the problem.

Вы были абсолютно правы! Файл env не был виден системой, я его просто не загрузила) После отправки на сервер все заработало!
